# Problem with NIS configuration

Tags: 14.04, networking, filesystem, configuration, init.d

I tried to configure NIS in a server and a client both running Ubuntu 14.04 following [this](https://boubakr92.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/install-and-configure-nis/) guide and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNISHowTo) official guide.

After a reboot the client machine got locked with this message several times repeated:

```
YPBINDPROC_DOMAIN: Domain not bound
```

any button couldn't be useful to exit and launch the GUI with a regular login.

I can normally use the machine only with the network disconnected (otherwise, it takes a long time even to open a terminal and sometimes the terminal window crashes).

It displays again tens of times the message `YPBINDPROC_DOMAIN: Domain not bound`.

The client machine is regularly indicated in the `/etc/hosts.allow` file of the server.

During the configuration, `rpcbind` was automatically installed instead of `portmap` and I couldn't run the command `sudo update-rc.d portmap defaults 10` at the beginning of the guide. Moreover, the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rpcbind restart
```

worked; but

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nis restart
```

didn't work because there was no `/etc/init.d/nis` file neither in the client nor in the server. I installed NIS with `sudo apt-get install nis`! Does Ubuntu 14.04 work different with respect to the previous versions?

And is it possible to recover from this situation?

(I moved here the question from [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com))

Answer (score 3):

From 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154656/etc-init-d-nis-missing-on-ubuntu/154661

> Not your fault, it's a bug in the documentation:
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nis/+bug/1303717
>
> The package uses upstart, which uses files in /etc/init/ rather than /etc/init.d/.

But I also don't know how to restart nis now...

Also, it seems like no one wants nis anymore
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259561&highlight=nis+14.04

Answer (score 2):

The package name is [`nis`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/nis), but the server's service name is `ypserv` and the client's service name is `ypbind`.

On the client side:

```
start ypbind
```

On the server side:

```
start ypserv
```

In the future use [`dpkg -L`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/nis/filelist) to find out which start scripts come with a package. Upstart scripts can be find under `/etc/inet`. Something like this should get you the info you want:

```
dpkg -L nis | grep inet
```